# Computational complexity of finding paths with specified product in a (group-labeled) directed graph

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, graph-theory, gr.group-theory

This question came up in the analysis of the puzzle game [*Swish*](https://www.thinkfun.com/products/swish/). One way of representing the solvability problem is this: given a directed graph $G$ where each edge of the graph is labeled with an element of a group $\mathcal{G}$ (in this case, $D_4$, but the question obviously makes sense for any group), is there a vertex $v\in G$ and a simple cycle in the graph starting at vertex $v$ where the product of the edges in the cycle is the identity of $\mathcal{G}$ (or some specified element $g\in\mathcal{G}$)?

The problem is obviously in NP, but I don't immediately see a reduction from anything like 3-SAT, or a dynamic programming approach to the problem that would solve it in polynomial time. What's the complexity of this problem?

Comment: Is the cycle required to be simple? If not, then it can be solved in time $O(|V(G)|^2 |\mathcal{G}|)$ by considering all starting points and doing dynamic programming over (vertex of G, element of $\mathcal{G}$) pairs. If it is required to be simple, then hamiltonian cycle can be reduced to it if allow arbitrary $\mathcal{G}$. So I guess the hard version which you are interested in is where $\mathcal{G}$ is fixed/small compared to $G$, and a simple cycle is required?

Comment: @Laakeri That's exactly right. I'm interested in the problem particularly for fixed small $\mathcal{G}$.

Comment: @D.W. 'Based' here just means a cycle and basepoint; since the product around the cycle can depend on where it's started from (if $\mathcal{G}$ is non-Abelian) I felt like it was worth calling out explicitly that this isn't strictly speaking _just_ a question about the cycle.

Comment: @D.W. Very nearly so! I was also looking for the vertex (and have tweaked your edit to say so), but that obviously has no bearing on the possible NP-completeness of the problem.

Comment: @NealYoung I do; mea culpa.